# JSP/Java/HTML | JSP out.println(); prints to console when in method

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat

I'm working a dynamic website with jsp.

Now my problem: when I use `<%`, to write my java, everything works perfectly fine.

```
<%
   out.println("<p>test</p>");
%>
```

But when i use the `<%!` like this:

```
<%!
  private void test() {
   out.println("<p>test</p>");
}
%>
```

My output will get displayed in my code editors console and not on my website as expected.

As import I used `<%@ page import="static java.lang.System.out" %>`. Is this the correct import or is the problem somewhere else?

If more information is needed please comment! :)

Comment: nothing is correct. You should avoid using scripplets. Always use JSTL

Comment: It is very strange importing anything from "java.lang" since it is already imported by default; and static imports are sheldom used too (I only see them in code generated for JUnit). It is more normal that you just use `System.out.println` anywhere. Anyway, you should seriously consider reading a manual/tutorial about JSP because it looks like you really do not know what you are doing.

Comment: @SpringLearner I'm learnig for school. But i will defnetly come to the JSTL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you probably know, JSPs are turned into servlets on-the-fly by the Java EE container. In a `<% ... %>` block, `out` is a local variable in the generated `_jspService` (or similar) method in the generated servlet. It's a `JspWriter` for writing to the output for the page.

In a `<%! ... %>` block, you're *outside* that generated `_jspService` (or similar) method, and so your static import means your `out` reference is to `System.out`, which isn't where the page output should be sent.

If you want to define methods in your JSP in `<%! ... %>` blocks, you'll have to pass `out` into them:

```
<%!
private void test(JspWriter out) throws IOException {
    out.println("<p>test</p>");
}
%>
```

---

About that JSP -> servlet thing, say we have this JSP:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    out.println("The current date/time is " + new java.util.Date());
    this.test(out, "Hi, Mom!");
%>
<%!
    private void test(JspWriter out, String msg) throws java.io.IOException {
        out.println(msg);
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that it has a `<%...%>` block and a `<%! ... %>` block.

The Java EE container turns that into something *somewhat like* the following. Note where our `test` method ended up, and where the code in our `<%...%>` block ended up (along with our raw JSP text/markup):

```
package org.apache.jsp;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;

public final class test_jsp extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
    implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent {

    private void test(JspWriter out, String msg) throws java.io.IOException {
        out.println(msg);
    }

    /* ...lots of setup stuff omitted... */

    public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

        PageContext pageContext = null;
        HttpSession session = null;
        ServletContext application = null;
        ServletConfig config = null;
        JspWriter out = null;
        Object page = this;
        JspWriter _jspx_out = null;
        PageContext _jspx_page_context = null;


        try {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            pageContext = _jspxFactory.getPageContext(this, request, response,
                        null, true, 8192, true);
            _jspx_page_context = pageContext;
            application = pageContext.getServletContext();
            config = pageContext.getServletConfig();
            session = pageContext.getSession();
            out = pageContext.getOut();
            _jspx_out = out;

            out.write("<!doctype html>\n");
            out.write("<html>\n");
            out.write("<head>\n");
            out.write("<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n");
            out.write("<title>Example</title>\n");
            out.write("</head>\n");
            out.write("<body>\n");

            out.println("The current date/time is " + new java.util.Date());
            this.test(out, "Hi, Mom!");

            out.write("\n");
            out.write("</body>\n");
            out.write("</html>\n");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            if (!(t instanceof SkipPageException)){
                out = _jspx_out;
                if (out != null && out.getBufferSize() != 0)
                    try { out.clearBuffer(); } catch (java.io.IOException e) {}
                if (_jspx_page_context != null) _jspx_page_context.handlePageException(t);
                else log(t.getMessage(), t);
            }
        } finally {
            _jspxFactory.releasePageContext(_jspx_page_context);
        }
    }
}
```